# What is the most effective way to iterate over a date range in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a Swift habit-building application.  At a certain point, a user selects the duration (in days) of the habit they'd like to create.  The user can also select which days of the week they'd like to practice it (sunday, monday, tuesday, etc.).  The start date is the day they create the habit.

I currently have the start date and end date (based on number of days selected by user).  Within that date range, however, I need to extract dates for the specific days the user has chosen.

My thinking is that for every weekday value 'x' within time interval (startDate, endDate), return Calendar date.  However, I have tried creating a DateInterval, and I am unable to iterate over it because it does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'.

Is there an efficient way of iterating over this date range and extracting these other dates?  Is there a better way that I'm not yet thinking of?

Here's my current date starter code below:

```
var date = Date()
var duration = 10
let calendar = Calendar.current

let dateEnding = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: duration, to: date as Date)!

//Returns a number representing day of the week.  i.e. 1 = Sunday
let weekDay = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)


//Initializing a time interval, based on user selected duration and start date
let timeInterval = DateInterval.init(start: date, end: dateEnding)
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the user will check off some weekdays and provide a duration as a number of days.

Assuming you have the selected weekdays in an array and the duration, you can get the list of matching dates as follows:

```
// User selected weekdays (1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday)
var selectedWeekdays = [2, 4, 6] // Example - Mon, Wed, Fri
var duration = 10 // Example - 10 days

let calendar = Calendar.current
var today = Date()
let dateEnding = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: duration, to: today)!

var matchingDates = [Date]()
// Finding matching dates at midnight - adjust as needed
let components = DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0) // midnight
calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: today, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime) { (date, strict, stop) in
    if let date = date {
        if date <= dateEnding {
            let weekDay = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
            print(date, weekDay)
            if selectedWeekdays.contains(weekDay) {
                matchingDates.append(date)
            }
        } else {
            stop = true
        }
    }
}

print("Matching dates = \(matchingDates)")
```

Comment: @OwenGodfrey In what way is this deprecated? All of these APIs are still in use.

Answer (score 36):

We can take a power of `Strideable` protocol:

```
extension Date: Strideable {
    public func distance(to other: Date) -> TimeInterval {
        return other.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    }

    public func advanced(by n: TimeInterval) -> Date {
        return self + n
    }
}
```

and then in your func:

```
// Iterate by 1 day
// Feel free to change this variable to iterate by week, month etc.
let dayDurationInSeconds: TimeInterval = 60*60*24
for date in stride(from: startDate, to: endDate, by: dayDurationInSeconds) {
    print(date)
}
```

Output:

```
2018-07-19 12:18:07 +0000
2018-07-20 12:18:07 +0000
2018-07-21 12:18:07 +0000
2018-07-22 12:18:07 +0000
2018-07-23 12:18:07 +0000
....
```

The code is taken from [this proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-make-foundation-date-conform-to-strideable/8100/32)

Comment: This option works perfectly with Swift 4 and Xcode 10

Comment: Unfortunately I ran into an infinite loop issue when the current day is **Jan 29, 30, or 31st** and you attempt to iterate through more than 40 days. Unclear as to why this edge case exists, but the **for loop will never terminate**.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I've updated my answer with a better solution. Instead of relying on `Calendar` it operates `TimeInterval`s directly.

Comment: Does this work with the daylight saving time? E.g. when the date interval would contain the day when the hour shifts?

Comment: @Cristik just like a plain `Date` this approach doesn't consider time zones. It operates with the absolute dates, so I assume the answer is no

Comment: I get this error: Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: Date, to: Date, by: Int)'.   Expected an argument list of type '(from: T, to: T, by: T.Stride)'

Comment: @brainray your "by" variable needs to be of type TimeInterval.

let dayDurationInSeconds: TimeInterval = 60*60*24

Comment: This proposal made into the Foundation framework. Now it's impossible to use it if you want to support below iOS 13

Comment: Days don't always last that amount of seconds. I would strongly advise using built in Calendar functions

Comment: In general, don't use this! As @LucasvanDongen says, days aren't always that constant number of seconds. And calendars are weirder than you think. Use `Calendar.enumerateDates()` as described in @rmaddy's answer instead.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startDate = ...
let endDate = ...
let dateRange = calendar.dateRange(startDate: startDate,
                                     endDate: endDate,
                                   stepUnits: .Day,
                                   stepValue: 1)

for date in dateRange {
    print("It's \(date)!")
}
```

Comment: This is Swift 2 code. Why? Swift 2 is long gone. Swift 4 is the current version.

Comment: Unfortunately dateRange is deprecated and no longer works in Swift 4.