# How to loop through Date Range?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Json Data which contains 2 Key:Value `"startDate":"2008.11",` and `"endDate":"2011.10",` respectively, and what i wanna do is to loop through the date range until this statement becomes false:

```
while startDate <= endDate { 
   let range += startDate + 1
   print(range)
}
 something similar like this.. .
```

how to loop through the date range in swift?

Comment: You say "+1" of what? Day? Year? Some explanation is needed.

Comment: So you want to loop by a "month increment"? Why not use real `(NS)Date` objects? There are easy method to add a month, day and other calulcations on `(NS)Calendar`, etc. to `(NS)Date`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857393/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-iterate-over-a-date-range-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have extracted the json values you can use DateComponents to calculate the number of months between the values

```
let startDate = "2008.11".split(separator: ".").compactMap {Int($0)}
let endDate = "2011.10".split(separator: ".").compactMap {Int($0)}

//Maybe add a check here that both arrays are of length 2
let startComponents = DateComponents(year: startDate[0], month: startDate[1])
let endComponents = DateComponents(year: endDate[0], month: endDate[1])

let months = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: startComponents, to: endComponents).month!
```

And now you can use a simple for loop

```
for n in 0..<months {
    //...
}
```

If you want to work with days (and dates) you can calculate them as

```
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startComponents, to: endComponents).day!
```

but you need to decide what day in month to use for `startDate` and `endDate`